# Not able to build a jar file in NetBeans program

Tags: java, netbeans

My NetBeans IDE compiles and runs the program fine and works good but when I want to `Clean and Build` using `Shift+F11` then it returns a RED color message : `BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds)`

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\ultronhouse11\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MeoPOSPrograms -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\ultronhouse11\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MeoPOSPrograms\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\ultronhouse11\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MeoPOSPrograms\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\ultronhouse11\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MeoPOSPrograms\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\ultronhouse11\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MeoPOSPrograms\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\ultronhouse11\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MeoPOSPrograms\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\ultronhouse11\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MeoPOSPrograms\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\ultronhouse11\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MeoPOSPrograms\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 717 source files to C:\Users\ultronhouse11\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MeoPOSPrograms\build\classes
**BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds)**
```

Comment: it's quite logic for a jar not to be built when the build is failed. But based on what you posted, I have no idea why

Comment: why build faild? i want to make jar file

Comment: as I already stated: "based on what you posted, I have no idea"

Comment: i have posted netbean ide console  output  message. have you idea about  it prograam run fine but doesn't make jar file...

Comment: Please provide some more details like what `ant-script` you are using to build the JAR. Snippets from your build.xml will also help others to understand and answer to your question.

Comment: Which NetBeans version are you really using? I doubt it's 7 and 8.x is also a bit outdated. As you can _run_ the project, this means that building the project basically works. Maybe it's related to the "clean" step. Does "Run -> Build project" (without clean) work? Did you enable "compile on save" in the project properties? Which Java version are you using?